# Retrieve bibliographic information from a list of digital object identifiers in a table

Tags: text, metadata, data-retrieval, doi

I have a list of digital object identifiers in a table, say:

DOI
10.1080/00076791.2011.617209
10.1017/S0007680512000037
10.1080/09537320802141494
10.1080/14765280802604771
10.1177/1744935908094085

I would like to find a way to look up the text of the abstract associated with the doi, the number of pages in the article, and the keywords and record it in the table next to each doi.

Is this possible at all? Where do I start?

(I use R Studio and R but I am open to all suggestions!)

Thank you in advance for considering answering this!

Comment: Can I point you towards crossref.org? I know people who've used it for this kind of thing, but I never have myself so I can't give any real detail.

Comment: Thank you @squaregoldfish that was the pointer I needed! I found this which seems to answer my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22266705/how-to-search-pubmed-or-other-databases-using-r/22271647#22271647